# Show that the basis of a linear representation T = L(X,Y) between two finite linear spaces, is in the dual space, and T is a representation.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, dual-spaces

I'm trying to review and teach myself functional analysis. I've done it years ago and trying to get back into it, and I did this proof and was wondering if it is correct or if I'm missing something.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional linear spaces equipped with bases $\Phi = \{\phi_1,..,\phi_m\}$ and $\Psi = \{\psi_1,...,\psi_n\}$, respectively, and let $T \in L(X,Y) = B(X,Y)$.

When $x = \sum_{j = 1}^m x_j\phi_j,$ show that $Tx = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\psi_i$ where $\vec y = \textbf{T}\vec x$ and $\textbf{T} = [\psi_i'(T(\phi_j)]_{1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq m}$, and $\Psi' = \{\psi_1',...,\psi_n'\}$ is the basis for $Y'$ that is dual to $\Psi$. The matrix $\textbf{T}$ is the representation of $T \in L(X,Y)$ equipped with $\Psi$ or $\Phi$, respectively.

**Proof**

The dual space of $Y$, $Y' = B(Y,\mathbb{F})$ These are continuous bounded functions from $Y$ to $F$. The basis of $Y'$, $\Psi'$ is given by bounded functions which span the whole set of bounded functions from $Y'$. $T(\pi_j) \in Y$, and $\psi'(T(\phi_j))\in \mathbb{F}$. This is just an element in $\mathbb{F}$. So you could see it as a coefficient for a vector in any vector space.

$\textbf{T}$ is a matrix, given by: $\textbf{T} = [\psi_i'(T(\phi_j)]_{1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq m}$. A matrix this would look like:

$$
\textbf{T} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \psi_1  '(T\psi_1) & \psi_1'(T\psi_2) & ... & \psi_1'(T\psi_m) \\
\psi_2'(T\psi_1) & ... & ... & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\psi_n'(T\psi_1) & ... & ... & ... 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

So let's call the matrix entries $\textbf{T}_{ij} = \psi_i'(T(\phi_j)$.
$$
Tx = T\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j\phi_j = \sum_{j = 1}^m x_jT(\phi_j).
$$
Then, $T(\phi_j)$ is some vector in $Y$ given by
$T(\phi_j) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_{ij} \psi_i$. Observe that
$$
\alpha_{ij} = \psi_i'(\sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_{kj} \psi_k) = \psi_i'(T(\phi_j)) = \mathbf T_{ij}.
$$
Finally, if $\vec y = \mathbf T \vec x$, then $y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf T_{ij} x_j$. From this, we get
$$
Tx = T\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j\phi_j = \sum_{j = 1}^m x_jT(\phi_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^m x_j\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbf T_{ij} \psi_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf T_{ij} x_j)\psi_i = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\psi_i
$$

Comment: Note how I reformatted your post; please make an effort to similarly space out your writing in the future so that it is more readable.

Comment: Also, your phrasing of the question is confusing: "The matrix $\textbf{T}$ is the representation of $T \in L(X,Y)$ equipped with $\Psi$ or $\Phi$, respectively" doesn't seem to be a part of what is actually being asked, but you have included it in both the title and question paragraph.

Comment: But yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: You do seem to have a typo in the matrix though; you've written $\psi_i'(T\psi_j)$ instead of $\psi'(T\phi_j)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. However, it could be presented more clearly and concisely. Here's an edit to demonstrate what I mean.

---

Let $\mathbf T_{ij} = \psi_i'(\phi_j)$ denote the entries of $\mathbf T$. For each $j = 1,\dots,m$, we observe that (by the definition of a dual basis)
$$
T(\phi_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n \psi_i'(T(\phi_j))\psi_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf T_{ij}\psi_i.
$$
If $\vec y = \mathbf T \vec x$, then $y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf T_{ij} x_j$. With this in mind, we observe that
$$
Tx = T\sum_{j = 1}^m x_j\phi_j = \sum_{j = 1}^m x_jT(\phi_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^m x_j\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbf T_{ij} \psi_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf T_{ij} x_j\right)\psi_i = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\psi_i,
$$
as desired.